# Need direction on best course of action with an lg16c with Kitkat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, lock-screens, usb, factory-reset

I have recently started teaching myself Android systems, and I'm not sure if I bricked or what happened. Now I could seriously use some direction as to the best course of action.

Somewhere in the process of rooting, uninstalling, and tinkering, I lost the ability to use my on screen keyboard. *Apps menu* showed the keyboard as still working but it was and is unuseable  I got the bright idea to try factory reset, as I wasn't using ADB at the time  Now the phone is formatted but I can't get to menu to turn on *developer options* for *usb debugging mode*
The touch screen is still operational but the keyboard isn't functional so I can't even get past the *initial setup* screen. 
Please someone, take pity on my stupidity and woeful ignorance. Any advice would be welcome. Its an LG L16C with kitkat
Oh yeah, before I had any idea what was what, I backed my phone up and then transferred the file to my pc. I haven't inspected the file as I have been tied up reading every piece of available literature on how to use ADB/SDK and trying to setup *remote viewing/pc control* and other such things.  Is it going to be possible to learn something from this other than *don't make that mistake again*?

Comment: Does the device have a custom recovery installed? Also, can you elaborate "*Apps menu showed the keyboard as still working*"?

Comment: ___UPDATE___  I have gotten the phone to load to homepage, however, since I did a factory reset and the keyboard still isn't working I can't sync it with my google acct. Still no keyboard, touch screen is working though..  USB Debugging is enabled again.  no root access to my knowledge.  Any ideas on how to use any program or chain of commands to allow my pc to type so I can sync google/android market?

Comment: or...  perhaps there is something I am just overlooking completely..  there isn't a backup on the phone, though I believe I have one backed up to pc. Not entirely certain how to load properly though. link to instructions or a point in the right direction would be freaking excellent

Comment: If you can get your hands on a factory image then use fastboot to flash a new system. There by restoring everything back to stock. For a quick fix maybe check the play store for a keyboard app.

Comment: Flash successful. Thanks much, really learned shoot through this